# Should the editor of an accepted answer also receive some credits (reputation)?

Tags: feature-request, edits, reputation

Sometimes there is a very broad answer and someone comes and makes and edit to improve it and include all the details. Later on the OP accepts that answer, but all the credit goes to the original person that posted the original answer.

Should the person that made the edits, on the accepted answer, also receive some credit? Or instead of an edit the person should have created a new answer and receive the credit as usual (upvotes/downvotes)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

If the editor wants credit then that person should post an answer (assuming they can provide enough additional details).

How would this work anyway. Can I edit your answer with a simple link, a typo correction, fix some minor formatting and get credit? How much credit should I get? Is the amount I get directly related to the type/amount of the edit?

I just see too many issues with this as shown in the above questions to warrant a change especially since there doesn't seem to be a problem. People who edit an existing answer usually do so because they feel they don't have enough to warrant an entirely new answer. And that's fine. I have never once edited an answer of someone else's and expected or even thought about getting any credit for it.

This is assuming by "credit" you mean reputation points. We do get credited with our username and profile link at the bottom of the answer and we get a place in the revision history. So, that always makes me feel warm and fluffy.

Comment: You only get the credit at the bottom until the next editor changes the dot into a comma (the one you forgot in between your 100 substantial improvements)

Comment: I share the same opinion. Especially when an author may provide a fully accepted solution [i.e the original version...] and then an 'editor' only brings minor aesthetic changes. That happened to me a couple of times. I have no objection against people bringing additional useful informations as code and specific technology may evolve overtime. 
Now if it's mainly done in a purpose of gaining credits and recognition,
as I've commonly seen, then I have only one comment: it's cheap.

Answer (score 7):

> edit to improve it and include all the details

Edits are there to improve the presentation of an answer, not to add additional content.  Such an edit would be an invalid edit, and shouldn't be made in the first place.

If someone has a lot of additional content to provide, they should be doing so through their own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has been brought up before. [On the old Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182724/217863) [in the before time...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114215/217863)

The problem with this proposal is that it is too easily gamed. Whats to prevent people from ninja editing good/clear answers in the hopes of reaping a little rep?

Low rep users already receive 2 rep for approved suggested edits and we have problems with some users gaming that system, more rep would probably lead to more gaming.