# Should the editor gain or lose reputation based on future votes on the post?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, downvotes, voting, upvotes

Why doesn't the editor of the question gain or lose reputation for every upvote or downvote after it is edited?

The reputation is only credited to the original person who asked the question, but at some point the latest editor should also get his/her due for every vote up or vote down as against only +2 points up in his reputation because that person contributed to the current state of the question.

Comment: Should you really gain reputation every time a question is up voted where all you did was change some indentation or fixed a typo?

Comment: while here are some cases where you make a major edit that saves the question completely, but those cases are rare.  It is more common to have a smaller edit that fixes a few things in an otherwise good question.  Why should someone get rep for that,

Comment: I guess some editor though have added few typos , but there are editors who change the way a question is seen and can attract a lot of users , there should be some distinction or credence  for such editor

Comment: And do you also propose that if you edit a question, you get a share of the future downvotes?

Comment: Could we get paid for edit? I am really good at capitalising `i -> I`! Btw there is some space befor evey `,` in your post! May I get some rep?

Comment: Yes both upvotes or downvotes

Comment: This model was [put in place on Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329450/603977). It's been toned down a bit, but it still doesn't hold up so well in comparison.

Comment: I feel some of the edits do save up the questions that questions which initially don't match up to the standards but after edits can get high volume of up votes that be checked out and editor be awarded after few margin of votes or a considerable amount of time

Comment: This would be an incredibly complex thing to implement and there are gigantic problems that would need solving to make it work. As Josh linked above, this has been tried in Documentation, but whether it's ultimately successful is still an open question.

Comment: [MSO: Should the editor of an accepted answer also receive some credits (reputation)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297521/247702) -- [MSE: Award reputation to an editor when edited post receives next upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182724/167646) -- [MSE: 'assist rep' after edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114215/167646)

Answer (score 13):

Edits exist to improve the presentation of the original author's ideas, not to provide your own, or to make changes to the underlying ideas presented by the author.  While these edits are helpful, the real value in an answer is the actual ideas and content of the author, even if you're helping other people digest that information more effectively.

From a less conceptual standpoint and from a more practical standpoint, it's also simply quite rare to see edits that really make radical improvements to posts, and make an otherwise low quality posts a really good or great post.  While, yes, it does happen that someone will have really valuable information that they post, but present it so poorly that the information is effectively useless to readers, and from time to time an editor will take such a post and actually polish it into realizing its potential, these edits make up a *very* small portion of edits made on the site.  Most edits are making small changes, turning already good posts into very marginally better posts, or polishing turds into posts that are still turds.

Next there are major problems with your particular proposal.  If you just give people rep for every upvote a question earns after it was edited, you encourage people to just go through all of the site's top voted posts, making entirely trivial (if not harmful) edits to the posts, just so that they can get rep from the votes the post is already earning.  Additionally, the people that are making the *really* good edits; the ones that are really turning posts around, and investing significant amounts of time into their edits, are the people that aren't doing it for a few Imaginary Internet Points.  They're doing it because they want to make the site better.  They're not likely to be doing a whole lot more of these types of edits just because edits can earn a bit more rep.  This means that the end result of your change is tons and tons and tons of trivial and/or harmful edits by people just wanting free rep for someone else's work, and little if any increase in the types of edits that we actually want people to be doing most.